# Troubleshooting Spyder launching

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I tried installing spyder using anaconda website. I downloaded the file and installed everything but as I tried to launch Spyder, it got struck on 'loading editor'. I closed it and tried again but the same thing is coming. I have tried usual things like reinstalling but the problem still persists. Please help me.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please deactivate your firewall/antivirus and try again.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I tried doing it, still no use. Is it that I didn't download it properly?